# UIScrollView -setContentInset not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've got a fairly straightforward scroll view setup, and I want to get rid of the contentInset.

MyViewController.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end
```

MyViewController.m

```
@interface MyViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    ...
}
```

In my storyboard, my scrollview starts from the bottom of the navbar. Unfortunately, I get the below result when running the app. Seems like the contentInset is still very much alive. I've made the scrollView background green.

[image: app]

**EDIT:** just providing a pic of the storyboard and the outlet link

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Still really struggling with this - is it ok to bump?

Comment: Try to add `[self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];` in `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Comment: or viewDidAppear:animated

Comment: Is `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` relevant?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the code

```
[self.myScrollViewOutlet setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

worked **only when** placed in `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

It **did not work** in `-(void)viewDidLoad`, `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` or `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

Hope that helps people in future!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

In your UIViewController which contains your WebView surprisingly named for example webView.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();

    webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero;
}
```